# How to customize alert notification mail body when user subscribe for alert

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, wss

I want to **customize initial alert notification message** body when any user subscribe for alert. I know how to customize alerts message using AlertTemplate from 12/14 hive template\xml folder, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution from Microsoft - [How to create a custom e-mail alert handler in Microsoft Office SharePoint Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948321/en-us)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I said I know about implementing IAlertNotificationHandler. This will send you alert once you assign it to user. What I want is the initial subscription message to be modified.